# NSTimer stopwatch with specific control

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, stopwatch

I have a label 00:00.0 and button. When I press button the timer should stars counting on label it's no matter how many clicks I'll do. The timer should stop when I tap on label, and should reset on second tap on same label.

**I tried everything, but I can't reach result :) Anybody please help me.**

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
    NSTimer *stopWatchTimer; // Store the timer that fires after a certain time
    NSDate *startDate; // Stores the date of the click on the start button
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
    - (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender;
    - (void)updateTimer;
```

Comment: Why don't you paste in some of the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)onStartpressed:(id)sender{
     NSTimer * timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(methodthatUpdateslabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}    

-(IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender{
[timer invalidate];
}
```

This should do it hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting some code inside my active project.

```
    -(void)start{
        [self setup];
        if(_timer == nil){
            _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kDefaultFireInterval target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            _counting = YES;
        }
    }


    -(void)pause{
        [_timer invalidate];
        _timer = nil;
        _counting = NO;
    }
```

That's the basic concept of implement a stopwatch, if you want to use UILabel as a stopwatch,  [MZTimerLabel](https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel/) is a perfect two line solution for you. Take a look.

Cheers.